# Why is $x^2 = f(a) => x = \sqrt{f(a)}$ AND$ -\sqrt{f(a)}$

Tags: functions

I don't understand why it also can be negative

Why is $x^2 = f(a) => x = \sqrt{f(a)}$ AND $-\sqrt{f(a)}$

Comment: $x=\pm y$ is an abbreviation for "$x=y$ OR $x=-y$" And in math, "A or B" does NOT mean that one of A,B is true and the other false.  If $x=\pm y$ and $y=0$ then $x=y$ and $x=-y$ are both true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actualy it is OR and not AND. $x$ can be one of them, it can't be both at the same time. It is equivalent to $$x^2-\sqrt{f(a)}^2=0$$ so

$$(x-\sqrt{f(a)})(x+\sqrt{f(a)})=0$$

Comment: Thanks I understand it now :)